# Merge MP3-files into audiobook with chapters?

Tags: itunes, mp3, audiobook

I want to take a folder full of mp3's, and merge it into an audiobook-file (for Ipod, don't remember the file format) with chapters for each file.

Is there a tool that will do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MP3 to iPod Audio Book Converter](http://www.freeipodsoftware.com/) will do this for you, it's free and open source.

Comment: ...And it works brilliantly

Comment: Tried that but it doesn't seem to mark chapters.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I've done it in my Mac ...

Placed all my *.mp3 files to a folder, and open Terminal to that folder ..  making sure my mp3 files are in correct sequence audio1.mp3 audio2.mp3 and so on ...

cat *.mp3 > Bookname.mp3

Then I went to Itune and added that big MP3 file to my Library  (Add to Library :))

When the Bookname.mp3 shows up under my Music, I right click on it, Get Info, Option and change the Music type to "AudioBook" type ...

That's it ..

Comment: This does not create chapters.

Answer (score 1):

[Audiobook Maker](http://audiobookmaker.sourceforge.net/) is free and open source for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I recommended [Audiobook Builder](http://www.splasm.com/audiobookbuilder) for [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/7173/how-do-i-convert-a-podcast-to-an-audiobook-music-track-in-itunes), and I'll do it again here. It costs 10USD, but is definitely worth it if you'll be creating more than a few audiobooks.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this in Windows using Audiobook Creator.  It appears to be free, but not open-source.  Setup is a little wonky, but it works fine after that.