# How to move a downloaded track into the Podcast section of the iTunes Library?

Tags: mac, itunes, podcasts

Pretty much the exact *opposite* of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/7173/how-do-i-convert-a-podcast-to-an-audiobook-music-track-in-itunes).  I subscribe to a podcast, and I recently found a bunch of old episodes available for download on the publisher's website.  When I add these manually-downloaded MP3's into iTunes, it puts them into the Music section (which I expect), but I'd really love for them to be grouped with the other podcast episodes instead.  Is there any way to do this?

I'm using iTunes 9.0.1 on Snow Leopard, in case it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Get Info window for a track, go to the Options tab. There should be a Media Kind field with a drop down selection box. You should be able to choose Podcast from that selector.

Also if you're using an old version of iTunes, I recommend upgrading to iTunes 9. It's free!

Comment: That did it!

By the way, I mentioned in the original question that I'm using iTunes 9 ;-)

Comment: There was a hint on macosxhints.com yesterday with these same instructions :-): http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20090923194952306

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this to work perfectly, but if you get info on the mp3's in question and change type to Podcast, they will appear in the Podcast section.  The more difficult thing would be to get them to sort into the same groups as the existing podcasts - which I believe is possible if you edit artist and album tags to match the group you would like to place them into (and possible either 'consolidate library' for the downloaded podcasts or manually move them to the correct podcast folder).

JDB

Comment: Hi JDB.  In the version of iTunes I am using, there is no Type field, but there is a Genre.  Is that what you're referring to?  I changed it to "Podcast" for the tracks and this did not seem to do anything.

Comment: Matt - this initially bit me too.  I think you're looking at the "Info" tab; check out the "Options" tab.